# webscraping with bs4 retrieving a text value

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/odds-movements/soccer/'

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "lxml")
times = soup.select('span.table-main__time') #good
matches = soup.find_all("td",class_ ="table-main__tt")

odds = soup.find_all("td",class_ ="table-main__odds")
```

[image]

the desired target for the scrape is the value here after `data-odd="value"`

I have tried `odds[0].a.text` to no avail

is there any advise on how to extract these values using `bs4`?

Comment: `find_all("a", {"data-odd": True})`
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39055066/1961688

Comment: thanks. the end result is just to have the values after data-odds in increments of 3 columns horizontially. get_text wont work here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieving the text output of a html website using bs4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73821496/retrieving-the-text-output-of-a-html-website-using-bs4)

Comment: Hi @HedgeHog, that worked for the text. But the result of the odds variable contains data not in a text format it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [docs for attributes](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes) and use `tag.get('attr')` if you’re not sure that `attr` is defined, just as you would with a Python `dictionary`.

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/odds-movements/soccer/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)

data = []

for m in soup.select('#odds-movements tr:has(.table-main__tt)'):
    data.append({
        'match':m.a.text,
        'time':m.span.text,
        'odds':[o.get('data-odd') for o in m.select('a[data-odd]')],
        'adapt':'the concept to add additional scraped information'
        
    })
data
```

##### Output

```
[{'match': 'Monterrey W - U.N.A.M.- Pumas W',
  'time': '04:00',
  'odds': ['1.32', '5.10', '6.56', '6.56'],
  'adapt': 'the concept to add additional scraped information'},
 {'match': 'Santamarina - Gimnasia Mendoza',
  'time': '01:30',
  'odds': ['3.37', '3.37', '2.85', '2.25'],
  'adapt': 'the concept to add additional scraped information'},
 {'match': 'Club America W - Pachuca W',
  'time': '02:00',
  'odds': ['1.77', '3.85', '3.53', '3.53'],
  'adapt': 'the concept to add additional scraped information'},...]
```

Comment: thank you that is a nifty piece of code,

Comment: url = 'https://www.betexplorer.com/odds-movements/soccer/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
best_odds = soup.find_all("td",class_ ="bestbet-odd")
x = [m.get('data-odd') for m in best_odds]

data = []
for m in soup.select('#odds-movements tr:has(.table-main__tt)'):
    data.append({
        'match':m.a.text,
        'time':m.span.text,
        'odds':[o.get('data-odd') for o in m.select('a[data-odd]')],
        'bestOdds':[[i[0:4] for i in x]]

    })

Comment: the last thing i need is to append each value to the line corresponding to the match, ie the first value in the list should fall under the best odds for the first match and so on, at the moment i am just returning all the values into each segment. any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not operating on the row as in my example,? What is the reason, to find all without any connection to a row?